# time condition for Autosys , which can run job for every 1 hour per day from Monday to Friday

Tags: linux, bash, automation, autosys

I need to schedule a job in Autosys in such a way that

it runs every hour/day

- it does run for every hour from 00:00 - 23:59 Monday- Friday
- What is the correct way to schedule this?

Comment: Hi, Autosys usage is out of scope on SO, which focuses on programming questions.  You should try other stack sites.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this should work :

```
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_mins: 00
run_window: "00:00-23:59"
```